# SQLite: Should using an index lead to roughly 100% CPU?

Tags: sqlite, search, indexing, io, pragma

While searching for rows in a very long table (~10 billion rows), **the CPU usage is only around 3% and the process is in `D` state**, which usually I had only seen with `INSERT`, not `SELECT`.

I am wondering if this is due to some misconfiguration and I could reach a better usage and thereby speed up the `SELECT`.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE key IN (SELECT key FROM temp);
```

Obviously the respective column `key` is indexed.

**EDIT:** I forgot to point out that I am looking for many rows by  and integer ids column (not unique). For example looking for 10,000 ids that each occurs 100 times on average.

**EDIT:** Here are some `PRAGMA` statements and their results, should it be useful:

- `PRAGMA journal_size_limit;
  -1`
- `PRAGMA journal_mode;
  delete`
- `PRAGMA cache_size;
  -2000`
- `PRAGMA cache_spill;
  483`
- `PRAGMA max_page_count;
  1073741823`
- `PRAGMA page_count;
  340456897`
- `PRAGMA user_version;
  0`

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (very possible!), how does "_100% CPU_" fit with "_only around 3%_" in the body? Other questions: is this single or multi-threaded/-processed? How many rows might you expect (1, some, millions etc.). Might also help to show the table/index definitions.

Comment: The question is whether searching with an index is expected to have a CPU or I/O bottleneck. The reason why I am asking this is because I observe what looks like an I/O bottleneck which I personally only expected for writing, not reading. But perhaps the index is so large that reading through it is bound by disk-read...

Comment: From a very quick test, selecting a unique row from 10 billion where there is an index is virtually instant (`.timer on` reports 0.009s) and the CPU doesn't flicker. Without an index, it takes about 10s (on a lowish-powered Windows box) and one core is maxed for at least several of those seconds. Therefore: your query probably **shouldn't** be a bottleneck if everything is "normal". Hence the request for the extra details to give someone a chance to spot what might be "not normal" about what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add extra PRAGMA details later. It is also my experience that without an index, the CPU is at 100% because it is just running through the rows from top to bottom.

Comment: TripeHound - Could you check searching for 10000 ids (`SELECT .. WHERE .. IN (..)`)? Does it take 10s? Maybe you can see the CPU usage then... Maybe my requirements are just too high. Because in fact I am looking for many ids.

Comment: From memory (I'm not near my PC at the moment), the original query (without the `IN` clause) was almost instant even when there were several thousand matches (when using an index). When I get a chance, I'll try with `IN` and report back.

Comment: Sorry: I've just realised that I missed some "noughts" off the counts my test DB... will retry and let you know.

Comment: Using what is almost certainly a _very_ simplified version of your tables (main table `huge ( id integer primary key, key integer )` and `temp ( key integer primary key )` and an index `idx on huge ( key )`... with 10 billion rows in `huge` (100,000,000 values of `key`, each occurring 100 times) and 10,000 random values of `key` in `temp`. Running `select sum(id), sum(key) from huge where key in ( select key from temp )` from the Sqlite3 CLI took 1.1s (according to `.timer on`) and barely any bump in CPU. [**cont**]

Comment: The `sum(...)` were to make sure it _used_ the values in each row (a straight `select *` would have also timed printing each row). What this _won't_ measure is the time to visit, and extract, any other fields from the main table. That is bound to be primarily disk-bound and will depend hugely on how big each record is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to think about the consequences...